# aggregating columns from dataframes across keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i have the following dictionary with 2 keys, each of whose values is a pandas dataframe.

```
x1 = np.random.randn(50)
x2 = np.random.randn(50)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':x2})

exampledict={'key1': df1, 'key2':df2}
```

i would like to create a new key in exampledict, called 'total' where the result is the sum of the values of the column x in each of the dataframes of each key. this example is intentionally simple but in practice 1) there could be many keys in exampledict (whose value will always be a dataframe) and 2) each dataframe could have other columns other than just 'x' so i would like to refer to that column directly. we can assume the indexes of each dataframe always match.

edit: i would like the result to be a dataframe also containing the sum of each element, with column 'x' and the same indexe

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
exampledict['total'] = np.sum([df['x'].values for df in exampledict.values()], axis=0)
```

Comment: i probably should have been more clear: i would like the result to be a dataframe also containing the sum of each element, with column 'x' and the same index

Answer (score 0):

You have to address the fact that the new 'total' key cannot be included in the sum... or else it will be adding the total to itself!

```
for key, value in exampledict.iteritems():
    for k, v in value.iteritems():
        if key != 'total':
            exampledict['total'] += v
```

Using iteritems() in case the dictionaries get huge.